# Using select to call function with input parameters in spring-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

We are trying to call a function in our database. The code is based on spring-jdbc. For local testing we use H2, while it is postgresql in production. The function call requires an input parameter and the response is a resultset with multiple columns.

We have tried different solutions:

1. Use JdbcTemplate and call the function with a select-query. The problem with this is that the input parameter is not set. The query works fine except it does not populate the inputVal.

`jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from func(?)", new RowMapper(), inputVal);`

This is the exception message:

```
Exception calling user-defined function: "func(null): null"; SQL statement
```

2. Use SimpleJdbcCall, withFunctionName and declare parameters. When we try to run this:

`Map result = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withFunctionName("func")
    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("inputVal", Types.NUMERIC))
    .executeFunction(Map.class, inputVal);`

It fails with the error message:

```
parameter count: 0)" not found; SQL statement:
```

Anyone have an idea on how we can fix this?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but.. Are you sure that `inputVal` is not null?

Comment: can u post  function signature?

Comment: We checked the value while debugging, it is set. The function is defined in H2 like this (just as a static java method): public static ResultSet func(BigDecimal inputVal)

Comment: did you find out the problem?